# Visual Studio Code 'open in browser' failed

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a macbook and am trying to use Visual Studio Code. I cannot seem to "open in browser". I installed the extension, made sure there was a default browser for visual studio code.

Every time I press open in browser, it will either give me an error code saying "cannot open in browser, check if there is a browser installed"?? which obviously it is, OR it will open to my Mac Finder folder and just stops there. If anyone can help please, it would be appreciated!

I tried to uninstall the extension and installed another one. that did not work.

I changed my default browser to see if that might do it (normally it is chrome, so I changed it to safari to see if that would help and it didnt)

I restarted visual studio code, nothing.

I also went into settings on visual studio code and saw the line for default browser was empty to I wrote chrome, and then restarted it and it still did not work.

The fact that it is either not opening and giving me an error message, or sometimes it loads but only to my Mac Finder folder (which is of no use), i find really strange, can't find anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: "open in browser" extension